# catch/create OnGetFocus/OnLostFocus events for TCustomControl Delphi

Tags: delphi, events, focus, components

I created a Delphi component inherited from TCustomControl. The component can get focused as inherited from TWinControl, but I need to "highlight" when its get focused and change some properties when it loses the focus.
As the Delphi documentation says, TCustomControl have no inherited OnFocus event, so I need to catch the event(?) and implement my own OnGetFocus/OnLostFocus event handlers(?).
How can I catch the events when the component get/lose the focus?

Comment: Override `DoEnter` and `DoExit` methods.

Comment: Thank you very mutch @TLama , thats exactly what Im looking for

Comment: @TLama: that should have been posted as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The events fired when the control receives or loses the input focus are [`OnEnter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.OnEnter) and [`OnExit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.OnExit) and are fired from the [`DoEnter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.DoEnter) and [`DoExit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.DoExit) methods which you as a component developer should override:

```
type
  TMyControl = class(TCustomControl)
  protected
    procedure DoEnter; override;
    procedure DoExit; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyControl }

procedure TMyControl.DoEnter;
begin
  inherited;
  // the control received the input focus, so do what you need here; note
  // that it's recommended to call inherited inside this method (which as
  // described in the reference should only fire the OnEnter event now)
end;

procedure TMyControl.DoExit;
begin
  inherited;
  // the control has lost the input focus, so do what you need here; note
  // that it's recommended to call inherited inside this method (which as
  // described in the reference should only fire the OnExit event now)
end;
```